# Multiple exclude in Django queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I use exclude chain in django queryset but it doesn't exclude properly.

```
skipped_questions = QuestionSkipped.objects.filter(user=request.user)
Question.objects.exclude(Q(id__in=skipped_questions) | Q(created_by=request.user))
```

Both Q parameters works normal individually but when I join them with OR it only filters `Q(created_by=request.user)`

I also tried both below but didn't work well either.

```
Question.objects.exclude(id__in=skipped_questions, created_by=request.user)
Question.objects.exclude(id__in=skipped_questions).exclude(created_by=request.user)
```

What is the right way to use multiple exclude for this case?

Comment: Are you sure, that `Question.objects.exclude(id__in=skipped_questions).exclude(created_by=request.user)` don't give needed result? According to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exclude), in that case `OR` operator is applied.

Comment: Which do you want: to "exclude skipped questions created by the user", or "exclude all of skipped questions, and also exclude all  created by the user"? Since your two options do different things.

Comment: You have to fetch list of skipped items id.  skipped_questions = QuestionSkipped.objects.filter(user=request.user).values_list('id', flat=True)

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
skipped_questions = QuestionSkipped.objects.filter(user=request.user).values_list('id', flat=True)
ques = Question.objects.exclude(id__in=skipped_questions) 
ques = ques.exclude(created_by=request.user)
```